# use look-behind in python to remove the trailing zeroes

Tags: python, regex

in the following string is there a way to remove the trailing zeroes, 
ie.
input is : '21006.08.094.000196'
o/p : '21006.8.94.196'

Though it works with 
l = re.sub(r"\.[0]*",".",str)
I was looking for a solution using look-ahead or look-behind expressions in python.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, those are *leading* zeroes. Trailing zeroes comes at the end of the string, e.g. `800`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
re.sub(r"(?<=\.)0+", "", "21006.08.094.000196")
```

This matches one or more zeros, but *only* if they are immediately preceded by a literal `.`. The `.` itself is not a part of the match, so you can replace the zeros with the empty string.

I don't see much reason to use this over `re.sub("\.0+", ".", str)`, though.

Comment: For input `"127.0.0.1"`, the zeros disappear. How about `r"\b0+\B"`?

Comment: It's not clear that's an issue; the OP's example isn't an IP address.